# Disqus API getting user access token via Python

Tags: python, access-token, disqus

I'm currently testing disqus API, and faced a problem: after i've got code (after user authenticated) when trying to get an access token via given [instructions](https://disqus.com/api/docs/auth/)

```
POST https://disqus.com/api/oauth/2.0/access_token/
       
grant_type=authorization_code&
client_id=PUBLIC_KEY&
client_secret=SECRET_KEY&
redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/oauth_redirect&
code=CODE
```

it returns me 405 when requesting as in instruction or 'parameter "grant_type" is required' if requesting as in my code. I use following code

```
payload = {'grant_type':'authorization_code',
        'client_id':data["client_id"],
        'client_secret':data["client_secret"],
        'redirect_uri':data["redirect_uri"],
        'code':data["code"],
        }
result = urlencode(payload, quote_via=quote_plus)
r = requests.post("https://disqus.com/api/oauth/2.0/access_token/?"+result)
```

I suspect,

> OAuth needs to be enabled for your API key.

causes this issue.

Any one knows what's wrong? If the problem is that my API key need to have OAuth enabled, then how can i do that (disqus documentation is a little bit inadequate)? Or the issue is in my code?